# Using SQLdatabase chains with Multiprompt chain in langchain

Tags: python, deep-learning, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I was using single sqldatabasechain but my default prompt is too long and utilizing too much credits from openai. In following code my default prompt has two messages inside 1st one is return result in table format if required else return simple answer. So I decided to use two SQLdatabse chain with separate prompts and connect them with Multipromptchain.

This is my code with single database chain

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
import os
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response

from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
# from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain import SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
import json
import re


def main(query):
    global db_chain


    prompt_default = ("""

You are a Sales Bot, and your goal is to provide answers based on the sales data stored in the database.

To retrieve information from the database, follow this process:

Receive a question or query from the user.
Formulate a syntactically correct query based on the question. Make sure to include relevant table names, columns, conditions, and any necessary aggregations or joins.
Execute the query on the sales database.
Examine the results obtained from the query.
Provide the answer to the user in the required format.
If answer is not required in table format, here's the format to use when responding:

Question: "Question from the user"
Query: "Query formulated based on the question"
Result: "Results obtained from executing the query"
Answer: "Final answer based on the result"

If answer is required in table format, respond in the following format:

{"table": {"columns": ["column1", "column2", ...], "data": [["value1", "value2", ...], ["value1", "value2", ...], ...]}}

Ensure that all strings in the "columns" list and data list are enclosed in double quotes.

For example:
{"table": {"columns": ["product_name", "sales_quantity"], "data": [["Product A", 100], ["Product B", 200], ...]}}

If you are unable to provide an answer, respond as follows:

{"answer": "I'm sorry, but I don't have that information at the moment."}

Remember to return all output as a string.

Now, let's proceed step by step. Below is the query:

Query: 


""" + query )

    sqlalchemy_url = f'sqlite:///../../../../notebooks/Chinook.db'

# OpenAI API key
    os.environ[
  "OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

# Set up langchain
    db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(sqlalchemy_url, view_support=True)
    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="text-davinci-003",max_tokens=1000)
    db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True,                               use_query_checker=True, top_k=20)

# First query
    result = db_chain.run(prompt_default)
    return result

query_run = main("Give me top 5 stock codes in a table format")

print(query_run)
```

Following code I tried with Multipromptchian

```
import os
from langchain.chains.router import MultiPromptChain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain, SQLDatabaseSequentialChain
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.router.llm_router import LLMRouterChain, RouterOutputParser
from langchain.chains.router.multi_prompt_prompt import MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE
from langchain import OpenAI, SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
import os
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response

table_template = """
You are a Sales Bot, and your goal is to provide answers based on the sales data stored in the BigQuery database.

BigQuery use variant of SQL that is standard SQL so your query should be standard sql query.

To retrieve information from the database, follow this process:

Receive a question or query from the user.
Formulate a syntactically correct BigQuery query based on the question. Make sure to include relevant table names, columns, conditions, and any necessary aggregations or joins.
Execute the BigQuery query on the sales database.
Examine the results obtained from the query.
Provide the answer to the user in the following format:

{"table": {"columns": ["column1", "column2", ...], "data": [["value1", "value2", ...], ["value1", "value2", ...], ...]}}

Ensure that all strings in the "columns" list and data list are enclosed in double quotes.

For example:
{"table": {"columns": ["product_name", "sales_quantity"], "data": [["Product A", "100"], ["Product B", "200"], ...]}}

If you are unable to provide an answer, please reply "I'm sorry, but I don't have that information at the moment.".

Remember to return all output as a string.

Now, let's proceed step by step. Below is the query:

Query:

{input}
"""


ans_template = """
You are a Sales Bot, and your goal is to provide answers based on the sales data stored in the BigQuery database.

BigQuery use variant of SQL that is standard SQL so your query should be standard sql query.

To retrieve information from the database, follow this process:

Receive a question or query from the user.
Formulate a syntactically correct BigQuery query based on the question. Make sure to include relevant table names, columns, conditions, and any necessary aggregations or joins.
Execute the BigQuery query on the sales database.
Examine the results obtained from the query.
Provide the answer to the user in the required format.
If answer is not required in table format, here's the format to use when responding:

Question: "Question from the user"
BigQuery Query: "BigQuery query formulated based on the question"
BigQuery Result: "Results obtained from executing the BigQuery query"
Answer: "Final answer based on the BigQuery result"

If you are unable to provide an answer, please reply as "I'm sorry, but I don't have that information at the moment.".

Remember to return all output as a string.

Now, let's proceed step by step. Below is the query:

Query:

{input}
"""
prompt_infos = [
    {
        "name": "table_format",
        "description": "Good for answering questions if user asks to generate a table",
        "prompt_template": table_template
    },
    {
        "name": "ans_format",
        "description": "Good for answering questions if user don't asks for any specific format",
        "prompt_template": ans_template
    }
]

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=1000)
sqlalchemy_url = f'sqlite:///../../../../notebooks/Chinook.db'
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(sqlalchemy_url, view_support=True)

destination_chains = {}
for p_info in prompt_infos:
    name = p_info["name"]
    prompt_template = p_info["prompt_template"]
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["input"], validate_template=False)
    chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True, prompt=prompt, use_query_checker=True, top_k=20)
    destination_chains[name] = chain
default_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm, output_key="text")

destinations = [f"{p['name']}: {p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)
router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(
    destinations=destinations_str
)
router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=router_template,
    input_variables=["input"],
    output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
    validate_template=False
)
router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)

chain = MultiPromptChain(router_chain=router_chain, destination_chains=destination_chains, default_chain=default_chain, verbose=True)

print(chain.run("Give me top 5 stock codes in a table format"))
```

I am facing this error now

```
ValidationError: 20 validation errors for MultiPromptChain
destination_chains -> table_format -> prompt
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
destination_chains -> table_format -> llm
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
destination_chains -> table_format -> database
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> input_key
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> llm_chain
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> query_checker_prompt
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> return_direct
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> return_intermediate_steps
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> top_k
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> table_format -> use_query_checker
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> prompt
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> llm
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> database
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> input_key
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> llm_chain
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> query_checker_prompt
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> return_direct
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> return_intermediate_steps
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> top_k
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
destination_chains -> ans_format -> use_query_checker
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

Comment: Same issue... any luck?

Comment: I opened this issue in on github and get replied after few days but not got enough time to test. check this out "https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/6444" and if it works let me know too.